# JQuery Datepicker Not Showing on my checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, woocommerce

The jQuery datepicker does not show on my checkout page and I can't figure out why.

The delivery date field appears but when you click the date picker doesn't show.

I'd be really grateful for any ideas how to solve this!

Here's the code:

`

```
$wpefield_version = '1.0';

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field'); 

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {    

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" , '', '', false);
wp_enqueue_style( 'datepicker', plugins_url('/css/datepicker.css', __FILE__) , '', '', true);

/*print(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/datepicker.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/datepicker.js"></script>'
    );
print('<script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/initialize-datepicker.js"></script>');*/

echo '<script language="javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").width("150px");
var formats = ["MM d, yy","MM d, yy"];
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").val("").datepicker({dateFormat: formats[1], minDate:1});
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").parent().after("<div id=\'order-desc\'><small style=font-size:10px;>Format (DD/MM/YY). We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date</small></div>");
```

;`

Comment: Include the datepicker script after you've included jquery-ui

Comment: You mean like this: wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" );

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
Change this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").width("150px");
var formats = ["MM d, yy","MM d, yy"];
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").val("").datepicker({dateFormat: formats[1], minDate:1});
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").parent().after("<div id=\'order-desc\'><small style=font-size:10px;>Format (DD/MM/YY). We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date</small></div>");
```

For this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").width("150px");
var formats = ["MM d, yy","MM d, yy"];
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").datepicker({dateFormat: formats[1], minDate:1});
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").parent().after("<div id=\'order-desc\'><small style=font-size:10px;>Format (DD/MM/YY). We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date</small></div>");
```

Make sure your jqueryui.js are loaded. Take a look on console from browser looking for errors.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still nothing. I think the jquery is not loading for the page but is fine everywhere else on the site ??